# Laravel 4.1 Eloquent ORM custom table name

Tags: laravel-4

I am creating api with Laravel. I have a table name "rfp_requests" and my ORM model name is Request. I saw in Laravel documentation in order to use custom table name I have to specify the table name that I did. But still it's not working. Here is my model code:

```
class Request extends Eloquent {
    /**
     * Database table used by model
     * @var string
     */

    protected   $table = 'rfp_requests';

}
```

Here is my controller code. I also tried to see the executed query. But it doesn't show anything.

```
class RequestController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $requestData = Request::all();
        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        Log::info($queries);
        return $requestData;
    }
}
```

Here is my route code:

```
Route::resource('requests', 'RequestController');
Route::model('requests', 'Request');
```

When I hit The url I see empty array.I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone show me  what is the correct way to specify custom table name in  Laravel Eloquent ORM.

Comment: After long research what i figured out I can't use Request as a model name because Request is a reserve method. See the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information.

Answer (score 0):

"Request" is not a reserve method, but a core class: 
http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/requests#request-information

You must change your class name to RfpRequest or something.